# Rendering component with no render method in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router

I have one question about React and Meteor. In Meteor App I make email verification `Accounts.verifyEmail` using React Router and here I have problem with passing params to the component. In component I would like only execute funtion without render anything. But I get an error `Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.` Could explain me how I can fix this?

routes.js

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import VerifyEmail from '../imports/ui/verifyEmail'

const routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route name="confirm-account" path="/confirm-account/:token" render = {(props)=><VerifyEmail {...props}/>}/>                 
    </Switch>
  </Router>    
)

export default routes
```

../imports/ui/verifyEmail.js

```
const VerifyEmail = ({match:{params}}) => {
  let token = params.token
  Accounts.verifyEmail(token, function(error){
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        console.log('Works')
    }
  })
};
```

export default VerifyEmail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

whether or not this should in fact be a component is debatable since it isn't in fact rendering anything, but in case you do need it to be a component, the error message you received is actually telling you how can solve this problem.

> Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

You can return null from your component to render nothing. Here is how.

```
const VerifyEmail = ({match:{params}}) => {
  let token = params.token
  Accounts.verifyEmail(token, function(error){
    if(error){
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        console.log('Works')
    }
  })

  return null;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Components need to have a render function. If VerifyEmail is not something that should be rendered but is only something that runs logic, maybe it should just be a function instead of a component.